# ERROR: requested 'ranchu' not available

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I want to try out the new Android-Emulators but get the following errors ( also for newly created AVDs ):

```
ERROR: requested 'ranchu' not available
classic backend is used
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Install SDK Tools preview 25 revision

Comment: Thanks - did not see the preview in the list - just installed the updates - WOOHOO is this nicely fast ;-)